# Соотнести и объединить ячейки в таблице

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

К одному ID соответствуют несколько product_id. Необходимо, например, чтобы в B4 были значения из E4:E7. То есть они должны соотноситься и объединяться. Желательно с разделителем "|", но не обязательно. Возможно ли это сделать? Excel 2019.
ссылка на скачивание документа https://disk.yandex.ru/i/7gCZ9VkPrEeoIQ
[image]

Comment: Можно макросом. Можно и формулами. В любом случае, в картинке эти варианты не сработают, а создавать  пример по картинке - кому это интересно?

Comment: сейчас прикреплю файл

Comment: И заодно (раз уж всё равно вопрос редактируете) - какую версию Excel используете? Есть в нём [**TEXTJOIN()**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)? В смысле [**ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ()**](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c?ui=ru-RU&rs=ru-RU&ad=RU)

Comment: ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ() работает

Comment: Отлично! Тогда всё просто - `{=ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ("|";1;ЕСЛИ($D$2:$D$300=D4;$E$2:$E$300;""))}` (формула массива, Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я не знала про массив) Только в формуле будет не D4, а А4, чтобы соотнести с первым столбцом